# Three simple jQuery steps not working - Set variable, print variable, compare variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Define Variable:

```
// Define Autocomplete Location Variable
var ac_location;
```

Set variable:

```
// Set Autocomplete Location Variable Equal to input id "loc"
$("#loc").val(ac_location);
```

Print variable:

```
// Print Autocomplete Variable
alert(ac_location);
```

Compare variable:

```
// Compare "#loc" input with ac_location variable
if (ac_location.val() != $("#loc")) {
// Print Autocomplete Variable
alert(ac_location);
} else {
alert("No match");
}
```

I have tried to use information from jquery help and google to do this. This is the complete code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NY3nG/2/

What is wrong with my steps, because console says my val is undefined and it doesnt print out the varialbe in the alert box. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i don't see any code that ever sets the value of `ac_location`?

Comment: I used this $("#loc").val(ac_location); to set the value of ac_location to what is in the input box id "loc"

Comment: `ac_location = $("#loc").val();` is what you want. that being said, `ac_location` will be a string, not a jquery element, so your comparison should be `if (ac_location != $("#loc").val()) {`

Comment: what is the value for `ac_location`?

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any advantage to making it a jquery element instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Set Autocomplete Location Variable Equal to input id "loc"
$("#loc").val(ac_location);
```

simply you set value of element `#loc` to `ac_location`, not vice versa. Do

```
ac_location = $("#loc").val();
```

and write `if` properly, your jquery object is `#loc` not `ac_location`

```
if ($("#loc").val() != ac_location)
```

and what's more, after comparison you `alert("No match");` when  your `if` statement ***matches***.

Answer (score 1):

if ac_location value is undefined the val function wont set its value, because undefined is treated as if u didnt give it any input variable -> jQuery thinks its a getter call

Answer (score 1):

I'm correcting your code:

Define Variable:

```
// Define Autocomplete Location Variable
// This is not a jquery object, just an ordinary js variable.
var ac_location;
```

Set variable:

```
// Set Autocomplete Location Variable Equal to input id "loc"
// You want to take the value of #loc to ac_location
ac_location = $("#loc").val();
```

Print variable:

```
// Print Autocomplete Variable
alert(ac_location);
```

Compare variable:

```
// Compare "#loc" input with ac_location variable
// ac_location is a string, compare it with value of #loc field:
if (ac_location != $("#loc").val()) {
    // Print Autocomplete Variable
    alert(ac_location);
} else {
    alert("No match");
}
```